# How to create an empty container and render it

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, containers

I want to create an empty container and get it rendered.
Currently my empty container isn't showing up.

```
<container name="empty-container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="my-class"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An empty container can be forced to render by including a text block.

```
<!-- Force container to render -->
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Thanks to https://gist.github.com/Quinten/47ed93666001938b988d

Comment: this solution doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Add this empty block to container.

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="empty-block">
    <action method="setText">
        <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></argument>
    </action>
</block>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to add a add a class or id to div element, you must wrap block in container element first

```
<container name="some.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container">
    <!-- Force container to render -->
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</container>
```